# FadeOut image at the top as it moves up with animate

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, fadeout

I have an absolutely positioned image that is being moved up using jquery animate. It is being hidden at the top and bottom by a div (The effect is the viewer sees an image scrolling up on a phone screen).

I now want the image to fade out as it reaches the top frame div. I think it will need to fadeOut just before it reaches the top of 'hider' div. I don't know how to make only the top of the image fade as it reaches this point.

HTML

```
 <div class="comments-hider">
     <img id="comments-feed" src="images/mobilestory-comments.png" alt="">
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.comments-hider-image{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 15px;
    height: 696px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    z-index: 700;
    width: 348px;
}

#comments-feed{
    position: absolute;
    top: -9px;
    left: 30px;
    width: 624px;
    z-index: 600;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$("#comments-feed").animate({'top': '-1500px'}, 12000);
```

MY ATTEMPT:

```
var topOfOthDiv = $("#comments-feed").offset().top;
var nearTheTop  = $(".comments-hider").position({ top: 100, left: -200 });
if(topOfOthDiv > nearTheTop ) { //scrolled past the other div?
       $("#comments-feed").fadeOut(100);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are looking for something like:

```
progress: function (animation, progress, remainingMs) {
    var h = $(this).position().top + $(this).height();
    if(h <= 0) {
        $(this).stop().animate({top: '-9px'});
    }
}
```

```js
$("#comments-feed").animate({
        top: '-1500px'
    },
    {
        duration: 12000,
        progress: function (animation, progress, remainingMs) {
            var h = $(this).position().top + $(this).height();
            if (h <= 0) { //go back
                $(this).stop().animate({top: '-9px'});
            }
        }
    });
```

```css
.comments-hider-image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 15px;
    height: 696px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    z-index: 700;
    width: 348px;
}

#comments-feed {
    position: absolute;
    top: -9px;
    left: 30px;
    width: 624px;
    z-index: 600;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="comments-hider">
    <img id="comments-feed" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff&text=1111" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this but I think I was misunderstood. I need the image to move up, as you have, but then fade out (at the top) as it reaches the top of the div it is in. The image is long. The div is short. Does that make sense?